# Stripe customer portal return url opens in new tab

Tags: stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe Checkout in my application. Once my customer is subscribed, I provide a link to the Stripe Customer Portal where the customer can see/manage subscription details.

I have issue with how Stripe Customer Portal behaves though... There is a link that says "Return to [MY_APP]". When I click it, my app's return url is opened in a new tab. While if I use browser navigation, I successfully return to my app.

This is also inconsistent with Stripe Checkout experience - if I use inbuilt back link on the Strip Checkout page, I return to my application while remaining on the same window/tab.

Is this behaviour perhaps configurable somewhere?

This is the html for the button to launch the customer portal:

```
<form action='/api/startStripePortalSession' method='POST'>
  <input type='hidden' name='customerId' value={customerId} onChange={() => {}} />
  <button type='submit'>Manage subscription</button>
</form>
```

And this is the endpoint that redirects to the portal:

```
export default async function startStripeBillingPortalSession(req, res) {

  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {apiVersion: '2020-08-27'})

  const portalSession = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
    customer: req.body.customerId
  })

  res.redirect(303, portalSession.url)
}
```

I set the default return url in the Stripe admin area.

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate this behavior. All portal/checkout sessions and returns occur in same tab.  Can you share the code you use to redirect your user to the customer portal?  If you examine the `<a>` links in the Customer portal do you a `target="_blank"`?

Comment: The `<a>` link does not containt `target="_blank"`, I just checked. Also, I updated my question to show how I initiate the customer portal.